# DropDownListFor not binding value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following ViewModel

```
    public class ContactAddViewModel
    {
        string _title;
        public ContactAddViewModel()
        {
            var titles = new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "Mr", Text= "Mr" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value= "Miss", Text="Miss" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "Mrs", Text= "Mrs" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "Ms", Text = "Ms" },
                new SelectListItem() { Value = "Dr", Text = "Dr" }
            };

            Titles = titles;
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; }
...
```

Called in a controller:

```
  var ctc = new ContactAddViewModel()
            {
                Title = contact.Title.Trim()
            };

  return View(ctc);
```

Then in the view:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control placeholder-no-fix" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
</div>
```

However none of the options are selected. I've verified that the title is correct, I've even tried manually setting:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Title")]
public string Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set
    {
        _title = value;
        foreach(var t in Titles)
        {
            if(t.Value == _title)
            {
                t.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging in the view, the correct `SelectListItem` has the `Selected` property set to true, however it isn't selected in the final markup.

Where am I going wrong? - I have other dropdowns in the model (that have numeric values if it makes any difference) that bind correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one's going to make you want to put your head through a wall. Do you happen to be using `ViewBag.Title` to set the page title in your view? That's pretty common.

Well, the first thing you need to understand is that setting the `Selected` property of a `SelectListItem` does absolute *jack all* in MVC. Razor automatically chooses which item to mark as selected based on `ModelState`, and will override anything you've manually set as selected.

`ModelState` is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag` and *finally* `Model`. Long and short, if you have a key in `Request`, or important to your issue here, a `ViewBag` member with the same name as your property, *that* value will be the set value for the HTML Razor generated. I'd imagine `ViewBag.Title` doesn't match anything in your `Titles` enumerable, so that's why it's unset. You'll need to name this property something else or change your `ViewBag.Title` to something like `ViewBag.PageTitle`.

Comment: lol I have fallen for this many times myself! I am very cautious now when naming model properties "Title". Its a annoying little trap. One time I had solved it by setting `ViewBag.Title` at the very bottom of the page view instead of at the top and that worked.

Comment: Haha of course it works like that, I must have been staring at the screen for over an hour and I genuinely don't think I'd have gotten that one, I'd have changed the property name in a blind attempt to fix things and moved on! Much appreciated, cheers Chris